# what is the best way to transfer data between android application and WPF desktop application over network

Tags: c#, android, wpf, network-programming

I 'm working on system that consisted of two part .first part is android application (client app) capture image and send to WPF application .second part is WPF application (server application) that receive that image , do some kind of processing on it and send back info about the image ,so what is the best way to make it work like server(WPF)/client(android) .

Comment: Wpf is for client desktop apps.  It's not appropriate for the server application you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ,I search about it and i found this framework [Eneter](http://www.eneter.net/ProductDownload.htm) and this Example on it [Android: How to communicate with .NET application via TCP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340714/Android-How-to-communicate-with-NET-application-vi) .

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTP, preferably [implementing as REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service, is the way to go. WPF/WCF and Android have libraries you can use to implement this. For Android, take a look at [Android's HTTP clients][http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) blog post.